# Load failed (IOS) and failed to fetch (Android) error in react app

Tags: reactjs, django, post, mobile, fetch

Now im trying to simply post json to django with fetch API but as mentioned on title error occurred in mobile device..

my reac post code is like this

```
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/uploading_firstName", {
      method: 'POST',
      body  : JSON.stringify({firstName: "kim",}),
      headers:{
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
      },
    });
```

im getting hard time with solving it since it works perfectly in window browser.
But when i do this on mobile device (IOS, Android) Load failed (IOS) and failed to fetch (Android) error occurs.

I'm not using any localhost urls and it added CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST on django setting as well.
Can anyone help me with these errors only happened in MOBILE device?

Comment: You hard-code `http://127.0.0.1` which is localhost on the windows box, hence working there, but when loaded from a mobile device will try to fetch from the mobile device, rather than where the django server is.  This should most likely be changed to the LAN IP of the windows box, assuming your mobile device is on the same network (wifi prob).

Comment: Thank you so much!! :)
I have no idea with localhost ip 127.0.0.1 but you made me exit from this issue.
Thanks alot!!